# If $f \colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then show that there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $\int_a^c f = \int_c^b f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

If $f \colon [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then show that there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $c \in [a,b]$ such that $\int_a^c f = \int_c^b f$.

I think that I have to proceed with the Mean Value Theorem of Integrals...

Comment: Under the assumption that $f$ is Riemann-integrable, I'd rather use continuity of $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: So, what is stopping you from proceeding with the Mean  Value Theorem (please add that to your post), and considering how that theorem might apply to your question. (Commentary, too, please add to your question.)

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function in $[a,b]$, we may define a function $F(x)$ such that

$F(x) = \int_a^x f(y)\;dy$

---

$F(x)$ will be continuous in $[a,b]$ and differenciable in $(a,b)$:

$F'(x) = f(x)$

$F(a) = 0 \;\; ; \;\; F(b) = \alpha$

([Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus))

---

By splitting the integrals, the problem becomes: show that $\,\exists \, c\in(a,b)$ such that

$F(c) = F(b) - F(c) \Leftrightarrow F(c) = \frac{1}{2}F(b)$

Since $F(c) \in[0,\alpha]$, the existence of $c$ can be directly proved by the
[Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

For $a\leq x \leq b$, let
$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\, dt$$
We want to find $c\in [a,b]$ such that $F(x)=\frac 1 2 F(b)$. $F(0)=0$, so either $0 \leq \frac 1 2F(b) \leq F(b)$ (in the case that $F(b)\geq 0$) or $0 \geq \frac 1 2F(b) \geq F(b)$ (in the face that $F(b)\leq 0$). In either case, since $F$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem guarantees the existence of $c\in [a,b]$ such that $F(c)=\frac 1 2 F(b)$. It follows that
$$\frac{1}{2}F(b)=\int_a^c f(t)\, dt = \int_c^b f(t)\, dt$$